# JPA+EclipseLink - Move entities in a @OneToMany relationship

Tags: jpa, one-to-many

my implementation of the OneToMany RelationsShip is like in this description:

http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/OneToMany

Entity Group:

```
@Entity
public class Group {

@OneToMany(cascade = { CascadeType.ALL }, orphanRemoval = true)
private List<Unit> units = new ArrayList<Unit>();

 public void addUnit(Unit unit) {
    this.units.add(unit);
    if (unit.getGroup() != this) {
        unit.setGroup(this);
 }
}
```

Entity Unit:

```
@Entity
public class Unit {

@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
private Group Group;

public void setGroup(Group Group) {
    this.Group = Group;
    if (Group != null && !Group.getGoodItems().contains(this)) {
        Group.getGoodItems().add(this);
    }
 }
}
```

Now I want to move 1 Unit between 2 Groups with:

unit.setGroup(group2);

After that operation I can see in the database in the relation table GROUP_UNIT
that unit now is related to group1 and also to group2.

How can I move a unit between 2 groups correctly?

Answer (score 1):

You should add the mappedBy in your annotation:

```
@OneToMany(cascade = { CascadeType.ALL }, orphanRemoval = true, mappedBy="Group")
private List<Unit> units = new ArrayList<Unit>();
```

With mappedBy you will not need the JOIN_TABLE anymore.